# Inner query with use variable

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am new to laravel and I am trying to retrieve data from three tables because the user enters 3 information then I use its to determine the row to check login 
so I use this way but not work! 
I do not know  how to send variables in SQL

```
DB::table('members')
        ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT FROM members_courses_assign WHERE referenceNumber=>$coursenum,termkey=>$semester) courseA'), function($join) {
            $join->on('members.externalPersonKey', '=', 'courseA.externalPersonKey');
        })->join(DB::raw('(SELECT courses  FROM  WHERE referenceNumber=>$coursenum,termkey=>$semester) coursecc '), function($join) {
            $join->on('courseA.referenceNumber', '=', 'coursecc.referenceNumber');
        })
        ->where(['jobID' => $jobid])->get();
```

Comment: What was the current output? give error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
->where('jobID',$jobid)->get();
```

Here in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) you can find all you need to know about query builder.

Answer (score 0):

To pass variable to inner query (Anonymous functions) you have to pass it with `use` keyword as [described in docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$yourVariable= "";
    DB::table('members')
                    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT FROM members_courses_assign WHERE referenceNumber=>$coursenum,termkey=>$semester) courseA'), function($join) use($yourVariable) {
                        $join->on('members.externalPersonKey', '=', 'courseA.externalPersonKey');
                    })->join(DB::raw('(SELECT courses  FROM  WHERE referenceNumber=>$coursenum,termkey=>$semester) coursecc '), function($join) use($yourVariable) {
                        $join->on('courseA.referenceNumber', '=', 'coursecc.referenceNumber');
                    })
                    ->where(['jobID' => $jobid])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('members')
    ->join('members_courses_assign', function($join) use ($coursenum, $semester) {
        $join->on('members.externalPersonKey', '=', 'members_courses_assign.externalPersonKey')
             ->where('referenceNumber', $coursenum)
             ->where('termkey', $semester);
    })
    ->join('courses', function($join) use ($coursenum, $semester) {
        $join->on('members_courses_assign.referenceNumber', '=', 'courses.referenceNumber')
             ->where('referenceNumber', $coursenum)
             ->where('termkey', $semester);
    })
    ->where('jobID', $jobid)
    ->get();
```

You can refer to Query Builder's advanced join clauses [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins).